# hidden elements in angularJS not compiled

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have a popup in my application that is hidden when page is loaded and it appears only on click on a specific button.
I have the following code inside my popup DOM

```
<a ng-click="settings();">welcome</a>
```

The same code works when i have it in my DOM that is visible when the page loads. But inside the popup, it does not work. It never goes inside the settings() function. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Define "hidden". Also, try without the semicolon in `settings()`. To improve the chance of getting help, set up a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) example which has the same problem.

Comment: By "hidden" elements, what i mean here is, I have a html partial that will be inserted to DOM directly on click. So any angular functions inside that DOM is not compiled. I know i can use $compile(jQuery('#partial_dom_id')) but can i use it inside the partial?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a directive for it. See the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/qFmP8/). Notice that a scope is applied to the return value of the compilation, effectively `var compiled=$compile(element.contents()); compiled($scope);`.

Note that there is already [a built-in include directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) in Angular which might do what you want. The example there responds to changes in a drop down, though you could easily adjust it to respond to a click event.